# Is it possible to access an AccuRev versioned file over HTTP?

Tags: accurev

With Subversion (SVN) we can view versioned files over HTTP i.e. we can view a Java file in a browser by supplying a URL such as:

http://teamserver/svn/repos/project/trunk/MyClass.java

Is it possible to do something similar with AccuRev? I only require read access to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.  You simply need to install the AccuRev WebUI, which you can download and install as a licensed AccuRev customer.

http://www.accurev.com/download.htm